# Docker - Build rpi image on Mac

Tags: architecture, docker, arm, raspberry-pi

This could be more generic and be building an image for architecture B with a machine architecture A. I currently want to create an image with lot of Python dependencies. Which take time on raspberry-pi but is faster on Mac. When I get an error at the end well need to rebuild. Is there a way to build this image on Mac and then pull it on my raspberry pi ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Emulating a full alternate architecture is generally very slow. [QEMU](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/HowToQemu) is what allows you to do this on Linux and can be integrated into a Docker container.

For building, you can use [QEMU User Emulation](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html) which is much quicker than full emulation. This allows your hardware to execute ARM binaries directly and is used to ease cross-compilation and cross-debugging.

First [get VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and [get Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) and install. (Or use [`docker-machine`](http://docs.docker.com/machine/) from the [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/docker-toolbox))

Setup your VM

```
mkdir raspbian-docker
cd raspbian-docker
vagrant init debian/jessie64
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

Now you are on your Debian Linux VM, setup the Docker host

```
sudo su -
apt-get install qemu-user-static
curl https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Run a raspbian environment

```
docker run -ti \
  --volume /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static:/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static \
  philipz/rpi-raspbian \
  bash
```

And do what you need to.

Then you can [`docker export`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) and [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/) to move images around. You can also use [the hub](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockerrepos/) or [setup a registry](https://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/) to use `push`/`pull`

The [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/docker-toolbox) will also allow you to easily run Docker via a VirtualBox VM on mac but I've run into more troubles than it's been worth (when you have vagrant setup).

Comment: Simple and nice solution and it works... I like it thanks.

Comment: I discover as well https://www.scaleway.com/. I could not register. no invitation but looks interesting to use for this purpose...

Answer (score 0):

You can fork RPI's distro builder and customise for your needs: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen
It uses qemu-debootstrap on Docker, similar to as Matt's answer.

If you plan to also build Docker images for arm architecture, qemu-debootstrap won't help.  In this case you can run Docker builds directly on an ARM server, such as the ones offered by Scaleway.

My CI server runs a combination of the above, to continuously build a OS image with pre-loaded armh docker images. Then, [device-init](https://github.com/hypriot/device-init) takes care of loading docker exports as docker images. 
The downside is that device-init can take hours to pre-load the docker images, after first boot.

Answer (score 0):

With the [buildx plugin](https://github.com/docker/buildx) for docker cli, it is much simpler to create an image for a specific architecture(or a multi-arch image) from a host with a different architecture. For example, a `linux/arm64` image(required for Macs with Apple M-series processors, AWS graviton instances, etc) can be built from a `linux/amd64`laptop(Intel Mac, PC, etc) using the below commands:

```
docker buildx create --name custombuilder \
  --driver docker-container --use --bootstrap
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 \
  --push -t example:latest .
```